# How should I handle authentication with Vue.js and users each owning a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, express, authentication, vue.js, account

When a user will use my application, they should have to login, and then have access to the application whose information is pulled from a MongoDB collection with all of their entries. Each user would have a collection, probably with their userID as the name of the collection.

If anyone is familiar with Habitica, that is pretty close to what I am trying to do.

I am using Vue.js, Express, MongoDB... Axios is used to create the CRUD requests, I believe. The only thing I have tried is looking up different ways of doing authentication, but I would like some guidance on where to start- as when I started learning full-stack development, I switched stacks a few different times before finding one that fit my needs (or what I thought I needed.)

I don't know my problem or what specific code I would need to post to get the right type of answers. As I get answers, I can post specific code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Each user would have a collection, probably with their userID as the name of the collection.

While it is possible to dynamically create a new collection for each user, I would not recommend doing this because any collection-specific settings (like indexes) would have to be duplicated and kept up to date across all collections. Instead, I would create a single collection, use a property like `userId` to store which user a document belongs to, and speed up database queries by [creating an index on that property](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/).

If you're not familiar with indexes, they're basically a way of saying "*I'll often query based on this property, please note down the values of this property separately so they can be accessed more quickly*".

---

> The only thing I have tried is looking up different ways of doing authentication, but I would like some guidance on where to start

An approach that is fairly popular with this kind of stack is using [JSON Web Tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token). Here's a quick overview of how you would implement these in your application:

1. Come up with a sort of password to securely sign the tokens. This can be a string of random characters. Store it somewhere your Express application can read it from (for example a `.env` file). This is your key.
2. When a user logs in from your Vue.js front-end, a request is sent to your Express back-end to validate the username and password (make sure to store passwords securely with something like [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)). If the credentials are correct, you can create an object containing the user ID and additional information you might want to use on the front-end (e.g. `{ id: 'myuserid', name: 'John Doe' }`). You can then [create a token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback) with the object as the payload and your key and return it in the response to the request.
3. The front-end can now store the token as a cookie or in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and from then on attach it to every request through a header. Since you're planning to use Axios, this is how you'd do that:

   ```
   axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
   ```
4. When you now make a request, your Express back-end can simply get the token from the header, [verify it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback), and extract the payload we've previously created. Since the token was signed using the key, you can trust what's in the payload and use it to, for example, get user-specific data by passing `payload.id` to a database query. This kind of logic is usually done in a middleware so all your application routes don't have to worry about *how* your authentication works.